# Add a URL parameter with a relative hyperlink

Tags: python, html, django

I have a URL that a user visits:

```
mysite.com/page/?q=query
```

On that page i want a relative hyperlink to move between pages, i.e.:

```
<a href="?page=2">Next Page</a>
```

However, if I do this it just replaces the entire previous query. Is there a way to have it just add to the query parameter?

Comment: Are you displaying a list of items and want to paginate through the items?

Answer (score 0):

I would use POST variables instead of your current GET querystrings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request.get_full_path`

e.g.

```
{{ request.get_full_path }}&page={{ next_page }} (mysite.com/page/?q=query&page=2)
```

However, you'll have a problem with just appending to the URL if you are on the next page, there will be more than 1 page parameter.

e.g.

```
mysite.com/page/?q=query&page=2&page=3
```

Best solution would be to use `request.path`

```
{{ request.path }}?q=query&page={{ next_page }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the complete query string with:

```
query_string = "?%s" %request.META['QUERY_STRING']
```

To only get the value of q:

```
if "q" in request.GET:
  q = request.GET.get('q')
```

With these variables you can construct your new link.